# How to tell Helm to ignore certain files?

Tags: helm, helm-selection

There are certain files I never access from Helm, such as those in my global .gitignore file:

```
# Emacs backup files #
##############################
*~
*#
```

etc.

Is there any way of telling Helm to ignore these files?

Comment: For grepping, there's `helm-grep-ignored-files` and `helm-grep-ignored-directories`. There's nothing like that for `helm-find-files`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know--if you post that as an answer I'll mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question directly, but if you are working on something Projectile recognizes as a project, you could try using `helm-projectile-find-file` instead of `helm-find-files`.  The functionality is rather different (it searches all file names and paths in the project simultaneously, rather than letting you navigate to individual directories in the project), but it does have the benefit that it understands and uses `.gitignore` files.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure when this functionality was introduced, but you can exclude files from `helm-find-files` by setting `helm-ff-skip-boring-files` to `t` and making sure the ignored pattern is on `helm-boring-file-regexp-list`. From its documentation:

> Non--nil to skip files matching regexps in `helm-boring-file-regexp-list`. This take effect in `helm-find-files` and file completion used by `helm-mode` i.e `helm-read-file-name`.

And the documentation for `helm-boring-file-regexp-list` says that by default it is built from `completion-ignored-extensions`.

Comment: This is just what I needed. I suspect if one really wanted there would be a way to append or replace those entries from your .gitignore. However, this for me more than suffices.

Answer (score 1):

For grepping, there's `helm-grep-ignored-files` and `helm-grep-ignored-directories`. There's nothing like that for `helm-find-files`.

Answer (score 1):

search that respects ignored dirs/files:

1. install `ack` (An alternative to grep.  I install via homebrew.)
2. put `--ignore-case` in your `~.ackrc` file (assuming you want to ignore case)
3. bind `helm-projectile-ack` to a key.  I do this in my emacs init via:

```
(use-package helm
  ...
  :bind (...
         ("C-c p s a" . helm-projectile-ack)
        )
  ...
)
```

4. create a `.projectile` file.  E.g.,

```
-.dot
-.jcs
-.svg
-.txt
```

use

```
C-c p s a     ;; search that respects .projectile ignore
```

or

```
C-c s p g     ;; search everything
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something in relation to using grep type searching and ignoring/including that might be a help. I use this (and it can be used with git-grep and similar if you locate the correct flags):-

```elisp
  (defun helm-projectile-ag-search-all()
    (interactive)
    (let((helm-ag--extra-options "--skip-vcs-ignores"))
      (helm-projectile-ag)))

  (defun helm-projectile-rg-search-all()
    (interactive)
    (let((helm-rg--extra-args "--no-ignore-vcs"))
      (helm-projectile-rg)))
```

ie override the default behaviour and do indeed search vcs ignored files... one key bound to helm-projectile-rg directly and the S-thatkey to helm-projectile-rg-search-all.

M projectile use-package is:-

```elisp
(use-package 
  projectile 
  :demand t
  :config       
  (use-package 
    helm-projectile 
    )
  (defun helm-projectile-ag-search-all()
    (interactive)
    (let((helm-ag--extra-options "--skip-vcs-ignores"))
      (helm-projectile-ag)))
  (defun helm-projectile-rg-search-all()
    (interactive)
    (let((helm-rg--extra-args "--no-ignore-vcs"))
      (helm-projectile-rg)))
  (helm-projectile-on)
  (projectile-global-mode)
  :bind ("<f2>" . 'projectile-dired) 
  ("<f3>" . 'helm-projectile-rg) 
  ("S-<f3>" . helm-projectile-rg-search-all) 
  ("<f4>" . 'helm-projectile-find-file-dwim) 
  ("<f5>" . 'helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer)
  (:map projectile-mode-map ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map))
  (:map projectile-command-map ("o"  . helm-multi-swoop-projectile))
  (:map projectile-command-map ("g"  . helm-git-grep))
  )
```